# Node.js and client session

Tags: node.js, session-cookies, mediawiki

I want to build a bot client in node.js for MediaWiki based sites like Wikipedia and Wikisource. One thing I have an issue with is that I need to send my login cookies with each request. Is there any library similar to Pythons cookielib that can help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the https://github.com/mikeal/request module and particulary

**request.cookie**

Function that creates a new cookie.

`request.cookie('cookie_string_here')`

**request.jar**

Function that creates a new cookie jar.

`request.jar()`

the module its pretty simple with nice documentation.